# Preview a PHP app on nitrous.io

Tags: nitrousio

I'm using the cloud IDE **nitrous.io** for developing a **php** app, 
and I want to ask if it's possible to **preview** my app using the preview menu?
thanks for help.

Comment: http://help.nitrous.io/preview/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: PHP is now available on Nitrous.IO. PHP5, Apache2, and Composer can be installed with the [Autoparts](http://help.nitrous.io/autoparts/) package manager. To install these tools, run each of the following commands within the console:

```
parts install php5
parts install apache2
parts install composer
```

You will also need to start the Apache server once installed.

```
parts start apache2
```

Take a look at the [PHP guide](http://help.nitrous.io/php/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

set in php.ini:

```
short_open_tag = On
```

or use `<?php`